# document.querySelector doesn't work in React Portal (Modal)

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

I'm trying to query all button elements inside my Modal that is implemented using React Portal. When I do:

`console.log(document.querySelectorAll('button'));`

it gives me an empty array in the console. I tested it in other components and it queries elements properly so I assumed that this issue is connected to my component being a Portal.

I have an internal state with steps and each steps renders a different UI. Some logic and styling depends on having a button there or not.

Is there a way to successfully query elements in the React Portal?

I've tried to do it with refs, like:

```
const refs = useRef([]);

const addRef = but => refs.current.push(but);

const hasButton = refs.current.length > 0;
```

However somehow this doesn't work too well for me and if it does it adds same element on every button interaction.

Comment: I recommend useRef

Comment: Can you please point me an example of how to query elements using refs?

Comment: It could be helpful if more context can be shared about the use case, such as the purpose behind querying all buttons in the modal.

Comment: done @JohnLi, also added something I tried with refs but doesn't work too well

Comment: Hi! At the very minimum please do provide a **minimal reproducible** example, you can use something like codesandbox with the react preset, so that we can help you.

Comment: I tried console.log(document.querySelectorAll('button')); it's working in my code, can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I suggest adding one wrapper class to your modal.
And then when you open that Modal based on the life cycle of the modal If it's hook based component the inside use Effect you can check like the below code .

Ex:-
consider this is your model

```
      const { React, ReactDOM } = window
const { useState, Fragment } = React
const { createPortal, render } = ReactDOM
const Outsider = () => createPortal(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.body)


const Modal = ({ children, onClose, open }) =>
  open ?
    createPortal(
      <div className='modal'>
        <button onClick={onClose} className='modal__close'>&times;</button>
        {children}
      </div>,
    document.body)
    : null

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Fragment>
    <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Show Modal?</button>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        Test Modal
      </Modal>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
  

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Inside UseEffect you can call something like this

```
const allButtons = document.querySelector('.modal').querySelectorAll("button")
```

I believe this should work in your case. If you want to go for Ref approach then here is one example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-villani-t4f82?file=/src/modalAndButton.jsx)